# Problemas con datatable

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, primefaces

Tengo un datatable que recoge todos los datos almacenados en una tabla de base de datos, esta tabla de la base de datos tiene 2 llaves foraneas y las cuales estan asociadas por su respectivo ID, el punto es que al momento de correr el aplicativo lo que quiero es que no se vea el ID de la tabla foranea sinó el nombre asociado a ese identificador, lo he intentado de varias maneras y no he logrado buenos resultados, adjunto parte de mi codigo:

```xhtml
<p:panel>
    <h:panelGrid columns="4" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
        <h:outputLabel value="DOCENTE"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{profesorporgradoBean.ppg.profesor}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{profesorBean.listaProfesor}" var="profe" 
                itemValue="#{profe.codprofesor}" itemLabel="#{profe.nombre}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <h:outputLabel value="ASIGNAR AL GRADO"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{profesorporgradoBean.ppg.grado}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{gradoBean.lista}" var="grado" 
                itemValue="#{grado.codgrado}" itemLabel="#{grado.nombre}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>

</p:panel>

<h:form id="formPrincipal">
    <p:dataTable value="#{profesorporgradoBean.lista}" var="l" rows="10" paginator="true" id="tblPrinciapl">
        <p:column headerText="ID">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{l.codprofesorporgrado}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="IDPROFESOR">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{l.profesor.codprofesor}"/>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{l.profesor.nombre}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="IDGRADO">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{l.grado.codgrado}"/>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{l.grado.nombre}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="AÑO">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{l.anio}"/>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Estas líneas son la que me están generando el error:

```
outputLabel value="#{l.profesor.nombre}"
```

Aquí el código de mi bean para la vista

```
@Named(value = "profesorporgradoBean")
@ViewScoped
public class profesorporgradoBean implements Serializable {

    private boolean enabled;
    private List<Profesorporgrado> lista;
    private Profesor profesor;
    private Grado grado;
    private Profesorporgrado ppg;

    private Integer codProfesor;
    private Integer codGrado;


    public profesorporgradoBean() {
        profesor = new Profesor();
        grado = new Grado();
        ppg = new Profesorporgrado();
    }


   //Getter y Setters

    public List<Profesorporgrado> getLista() {

        profesorporgradoDao pgDao = new profesorporgradoDaoImp();
        lista = pgDao.BuscarTodos();

        return lista;
    }

    public void setLista(List<Profesorporgrado> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }
}
```

La traza que me lanza es la siguiente

> FATAL:   JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.el.ELException durante el
>   procesamiento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=,
>   Mensaje=/Vistas/profesor/profexgrado.xhtml @50,74
>   value="#{l.profesor.nombre}":
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session FATAL:   /Vistas/profesor/profexgrado.xhtml @50,74 value="#{l.profesor.nombre}":
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session javax.el.ELException: /Vistas/profesor/profexgrado.xhtml @50,74 value="#{l.profesor.nombre}":
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session  at co

mi entity profesorporgrado es el siguiente

```
package com.model;
// Generated 22/04/2017 06:11:52 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Profesorporgrado generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Profesorporgrado  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer codprofesorporgrado;
     private Grado grado;
     private Profesor profesor;
     private String anio;
     private Date fecha;

    public Profesorporgrado() {
    }

    public Profesorporgrado(Grado grado, Profesor profesor, String anio, Date fecha) {
       this.grado = grado;
       this.profesor = profesor;
       this.anio = anio;
       this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Integer getCodprofesorporgrado() {
        return this.codprofesorporgrado;
    }

    public void setCodprofesorporgrado(Integer codprofesorporgrado) {
        this.codprofesorporgrado = codprofesorporgrado;
    }
    public Grado getGrado() {
        return this.grado;
    }

    public void setGrado(Grado grado) {
        this.grado = grado;
    }
    public Profesor getProfesor() {
        return this.profesor;
    }

    public void setProfesor(Profesor profesor) {
        this.profesor = profesor;
    }
    public String getAnio() {
        return this.anio;
    }

    public void setAnio(String anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }
    public Date getFecha() {
        return this.fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }




}
```

este es el método que hace la consulta a la tabla profesor de la base de datos es

```
public Profesor buscarporId(Session session, Integer codProfesor) {
       String hql = "FROM Profesor WHERE codProfesor = :codProfesor";
       Query q = session.createQuery(hql);
       q.setParameter("codProfesor", codProfesor);

       return (Profesor) q.uniqueResult();
    }
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar como tienes tu entity Profesorporgrado pudiera ser que el problema este en el ToString, o si en tu consulta haces lo joins necesarios para recuperar toda la información

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema de este código? ¿no compila, lanza una excepción, se ejecuta pero muestra un valor inesperado?

Comment: me lanza un error fatal, ya hice la modificacion al post para que puedan ver la traza que me arroja

Comment: Puedes mostrar la consulta este error regularmente se da ahí

Comment: Hola @SoftMolina ya publiqué el método que uso para buscar un  profesor y fijate que me devuelve todo un objeto de tipo Profesor, pero aun así no se que puede estar mal.